# Creating new orders with Python API, get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Tags: python, json, shopify

The code I have that's causing this is

```
    new_order = shopify.Order.create(json.dumps({'order': { "email": "foo@example.com", "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled", "line_items": [{'message': "words go here"}]}}))
```

I tried without the json.dumps and got the response that it was an unhashable type. also tried this from some reasearch

```
data = dict()
data['order']= { "email": "foo@example.com", "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled", "line_items": [{'message': "words go here"}]}
print(data['order'])
new_order = shopify.Order.create(json.dumps(data))
```

What can I do to properly send in a simple order like in https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#create

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Kris/Desktop/moon_story/story_app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kris/Desktop/moon_story/story_app.py", line 41, in <module>
{'fulfillment_status': 'fulfilled', 'email': 'foo@example.com', 'line_items': [{'message': 'words go here'}]}
    get_story(1520)
  File "C:/Users/Kris/Desktop/moon_story/story_app.py", line 29, in get_story
    new_order = shopify.Order.create(json.dumps(data))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyactiveresource\activeresource.py", line 448, in create
    resource = cls(attributes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\shopify\base.py", line 126, in __init__
    prefix_options, attributes = self.__class__._split_options(attributes)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyactiveresource\activeresource.py", line 465, in _split_options
    for key, value in six.iteritems(options):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 599, in iteritems
    return d.iteritems(**kw)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: what is the full error trace?

Comment: edited it into OP

Comment: @moardee did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment**: ... get an order(None) as response. ... Any thoughts?

Comparing with [help.shopify.com/api/reference](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#create) there are the following differences:

1. The Endpoint have to be `/admin/orders.json`

   Why do you use `/admin`?
2. The **Main** Key in the JSON Dict have to be `order`.

   Why don't you use this, for example:

   ```
   {
     "order": {
       "email": "foo@example.com",
       "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
       "line_items": [
         {
           "variant_id": 447654529,
           "quantity": 1
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

---

Use:

```
new_order = shopify.Order.create(data['order'])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: I've tried doing what you say, but get an order(None) as response. I've tried it a couple of different ways, not sure exactly what's off. Any thoughts?

Comment: @stovfl `order(None)` could still be the case if there was a problem creating the order, it's only how the class object is displayed. If you look at the object, you'll see that it does have the attributes that you've added, just wasn't successfully saved. See my answer for details.

Comment: I see your point. Yes, I get `False` as response, `order(None)` as return

Comment: @jordan: Updated my Answer

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I was able to get this working. You shouldn't need to do anything special with the argument passed to `create`. The following works for me:

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@%s.myshopify.com/admin" % (shopify_key, shopify_pass, shopify_store_name)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)

order_data = {
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
        "line_items": [
            { 
                "title": "ITEM TITLE",
                "variant_id": 7214792579,
                "quantity": 1,
                "price": 895
            }
        ]
    }

shopify.Order.create(order_data)
```

It's worth noting that this Python library relies on another Shopify created library called [pyactiveresource](https://github.com/Shopify/pyactiveresource/blob/master/pyactiveresource/activeresource.py). That library provides the underlying `create` method, which calls the `save` method.

The save method has the following notes about responses:

```
Args:
  None
Returns:
  True on success, False on ResourceInvalid errors (sets the errors
  attribute if an <errors> object is returned by the server).
Raises:
  connection.Error: On any communications problems.
```

I was continually getting a `False` response. This helped me understand which fields were actually required by looking at the `errors` attribute, so I figured it might be helpful here.